# Function with a cursor, cant find the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not quite sure what I typed in that was wrong. This is the error I receive from my SQL code:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GradeAverage, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near 'myCursor'.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GradeAverage 
   (@StudentID as varchar(20)) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Final int
    DECLARE @Grade int
    DECLARE @Total int= 0
    DECLARE @Count int = 0

    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT FinalGrade
        FROM CourseEnrollment
        WHERE StudentId = @StudentID AND FinalGrade IS NOT NULL

    OPEN myCursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Grade

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Total = @Grade + @Total;
        SET @Count = @Count +1;

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Grade
    END

    SET @Final = (@Total/@Count);

    CLOSE myCursor
    DEALLOCATE myCursor

    RETURNS @Final
```

Comment: I believe the problem is the last line. `RETURNS @Final` should be `RETURN @Final` (no S).

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GradeAverage, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near '@Final'.

Comment: Are you missing an `END`?

Comment: I considered voting to close this question as it was mostly just a typographical error, but I felt there was enough here to warrant a complete answer. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `RETURNS` declares the return *type* of the function as in `RETURNS int`, but to actually specify the return *value*, you need to use `RETURN` (no `S`):

The second problem is that each `BEGIN` in your function definition must be matched with an `END`, including the `BEGIN`/`END` which surrounds your entire function body.

Finally, for the sake of readability, I suggest you adopt some more standard formatting conventions. It should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GradeAverage (@StudentID as varchar(20)) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Final int;
    DECLARE @Grade int;
    DECLARE @Total int= 0;
    DECLARE @Count int = 0;
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT FinalGrade
        FROM CourseEnrollment
        WHERE StudentId = @StudentID AND FinalGrade IS NOT NULL;
    OPEN myCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Grade;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Total = @Grade + @Total;
        SET @Count = @Count +1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Grade;
    END
    SET @Final = (@Total/@Count);
    CLOSE myCursor;
    DEALLOCATE myCursor;
    RETURN @Final;
END
```